# Not able to resolve identify member class attribute in android studio

Tags: java, android, subclass, members

```
package com.example.android.sunshine;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new DetailFragment())
                    .commit();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.detailfragment, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider= (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
        if(mShareActionProvider!=null)
        {
            mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareForecastIntent());
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,"Amen");
        }
        //return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

         startActivity(new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class));
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {


        private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
        private static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #SunshineApp";
        private String mForecastStr;

        public DetailFragment() {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
                mForecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text)).setText(mForecastStr);
            }
            return rootView;
        }


        private Intent createShareForecastIntent() {
            Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecastStr + FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
            return shareIntent;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above when the line in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` where I use LOG_TAG and where I use `createShareForecastIntent` says cannot resolve symbol and method. I tried googling it but couldn't find anything. I am new to `android` and `java` both.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `createShareForecastIntent` as `static` since `FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG` is `static`. if you want to use them inside a ***non-static*** class method, you can either declare it *public* and call it like this: `DetailFragment.FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG`, or simply declare the method that's using it without class reference as `static`.

i.e.:

```
public static final String FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG = " #SunshineApp";


// call it like this, referencing the class name
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mForecastStr + DetailFragment.FORECAST_SHARE_HASHTAG);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define LOG_TAG in your DetailActivity first as such:

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = "Some tag string";
```

Comment: I want to use members of the nested class and not from the main class. That is the entire point of the question.

Comment: Then change your LOG_TAG to public static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();